# Swift 3: Check for item in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

I would like to check if an item exists in an array:

```
 protocol Item {
        var name: String! {get set}
        var value: Int! {get set}
    }

class UserList {
    var items: [Item]!

    func checkItem(item: Item) -> Bool{
        if items.contains(where: {$0 === item}) {  // Error
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'Item' operands
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use identity operator (`===`) for your `checkItem`, you can declare your `Item` as a class protocol:

```
protocol Item: class {
    var name: String! {get set}
    var value: Int! {get set}
}

class UserList {
    var items: [Item]!

    func checkItem(item: Item) -> Bool{
        return items.contains {$0 === item}
    }
}
```

(I do not understand why you need implicitly unwrapped Optionals, so I have kept them there. But I myself would never use so many IUOs.)

---

But I wonder if identity is what you want:

```
class ClassItem: Item {
    var name: String!
    var value: Int!

    init(_ name: String, _ value: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}
let myList = UserList()
myList.items = [ClassItem("aaa", 1), ClassItem("bbb", 2)]
var result = myList.checkItem(item: ClassItem("aaa", 1))
print(result) //->false
```

If the result `false` is not what you expect, you need to define your own *equality* for the `Item` and define your `checkItem(item:)` with it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this simple solution, that comes from objecitve-c

```
let array = ["a,b"]
if let _ = array.index(of: "b")
{
    //if "b" is in array         
}
else
{
    //if "b" is not in aray
}
```